# IBM WebSphere MQ Client - unlimited wait GET vs. correlation GET

Tags: ibm-mq

I am trying to build with **amqmdnet** a IBM MQ receiver with 2 functionalities:

- **ReceiveReply(byte correlationId)** – reads *REPLY* messages for supplied correlation identifiers. Is implemented by a GET with a correlation MATCH.
- **event EventHandler NewMessage** – notifies the subscriber of new *REQUEST* messages. Is implemented by a GET with unlimited wait in infinite while loop.

The problem is that I cannot limit the second GET to read only *REQUEST* messages and so the correlation GET is never successful. If I only do one GET I will have to implement correlation on my own.

Anyone tried to implement something similar?

Thanks,
Radu

Answer (score 3):

The simplest option is to use two queues. There are ugly ways of achieving what you are after (imagine all request messages putting something in the correlid so you could get by correlid there too, for example) but in principle you have a request queue and a reply queue - dont share!

Comment: I already use two queues but both server and client send requests and responses. So that doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: 4 queues? :-)  Just a thought, would need investigation, but you might be able to make use of the SelectionString on the MQOPEN, and message properties to tag request/replies. See figure 2 on http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.mq.doc%2Ffg20160_.htm

Comment: You say you're already using two queues, but if you are, you don't appear to be separating requests from responses. Where Jason said use two queues, he meant put the requests on a separate queue from the responses.